# What is the best normalization design for Redux store?

Tags: redux, react-redux

Should I just copy the database relationships, or are there good patterns to follow? In the Redux documentation it says that the tables should not be a lust but objects mapped by it's ids, and also have a list containing all IDs. It does not provide any example of how it can be useful though. I've seen some other random designs... What design is the most accepted in the community?

Comment: What specific aspects of the [Normalizing State Shape docs page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) do you feel are not clear?  Can you clarify what you mean by "it does not provide any example of how it can be useful" ?

Comment: Transform a list of objects in a map. How is this going to help me?

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I still don't understand what aspects you're specifically asking about.  If you're asking how to handle immutable updates, see the ["Immutable Update Patterns" docs page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns), and the article [The Complete Guide to Immutability in React and Redux](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For managing normalized reducer state, use [normalized-reducer](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer). It's a higher-order-reducer that takes a schema describing the relationships, and returns a reducer, actions, and selectors that write/read according to the relationships. It also integrates easily with Normalizr and Redux Toolkit.